# "GeneralException" raised using office.je API

Tags: office-js

When i execute my code using the office.js API, the following error is raised :

**JavaScript: GeneralException: There was an internal error while processing the request.**

Can someone explain me what means this error. 
And what can cause this error ?

Thanks :-)

To precise my problem, i do something like this :

```
    var range = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1").getRange("B6:F8");
    range.numberFormat = [["0", "0", "0","0","0"], ["0", "0", "0","0","0"], ["0", "0", "0","0","0"]];
    range.values = [["sample", "a", "2","5","23.8095238095238"], ["", "b", "2","7","33.3333333333333"], ["", "c", "2","9","42.8571428571429"]];
```

This procedure work well in one function call, but in another it raised the "GeneralException" !!!

What's the hell ;-)

Comment: It is because you have written a code that throws `GeneralException`. Unless you share the code with us, how can you expect us to solve your problem?

Comment: My code is too long to be share !!! The error is raised by the Office.js API. Exception raised in row 19, column 142076 in https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1.1/hosted/excel-win32-16.00.js.

Comment: Sorry, we are not mind readers.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: I don't tell you to solve my problem, but what this error means when it is raised by the api office.js !!!

Comment: Looks like the project you are working on has less support or documentation. Fond this: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/excel/excel-add-ins-programming-overview.md Do you feel that's helpful?

Comment: Thanks but i worked a lot of with this doc, but i don't find answer for this problem. May be i must contact the office.js team.

Comment: Could be, buddy. Sorry we are not able to help you.

Comment: Would you mind showing us a line that reproduces such an exception? It's hard to help you without seeing the code.

Comment: Hello @GabRoyer, i have completed my question with some code.

Comment: The code you've posted works fine for me. You said this only happens when it's inside of a function, can you post the said function's full body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was fixed, I just verified your code, No general exception was observed. please validate, kindly create a new issue or report it via [office-js issue](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues) in github if you still observe general exception error